# Where should we post cocoa/Objective-C questions now that there is a apple.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I see that the apple.stackexchange.com FAQ and description describe it as being intended for power Apple product users. Does this mean that we should continue to post questions about Cocoa and objective-C that are programming related here on stackoverflow? Do you think that programming questions might start to trickle into the apple site?

what about things like shell programming or other scripting on the Mac?